# JSON, CSV and Python

Tags: csv, javascript-objects

I have a CSV file with a column with JSON formatted data. 
How can I extract the JSON data into a CSV file that can be processed in Access or SQL?

What code language can be used and how will that code look like?

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Are you looking for examples in Python?

Comment: Sounds like you already have CSV file?

Comment: I have a CSV file with JASON formated data where each column holds a JASON String, is there a method I can use to extract that information within the JASON column to a new CSV file

Comment: I have been told that Python is an easy way to get it done, I am open to a more simple proposal if there is one :-)

Comment: I think it would help if you can show us some of your JSON file, because -if I understand correctly- you would like to extract one column out of it and convert that to CSV? Are you open for PowerShell?